# Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition Wizard work's not correctly

Tags: html, visual-c++, wizard

I have Windows Vista, Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition. I'm trying to create a dll. So, I take next steps: File - Create - Project - Win32 - Win32 Console Application (it have to be a wizard). And I was expecting for this window: http://img244.imageshack.us/i/vs3ae4.jpg/ But I've got next situation: http://img30.imageshack.us/i/msvs1.jpg/ It's in russian, but I can translate. The front window tells: "Open or save file?" If I press "Open" my web-browser (FireFox) opens and shows me the web-page: http://img268.imageshack.us/i/msvs3.jpg/ It's like what I was expecting for http://img244.imageshack.us/i/vs3ae4.jpg/, but in the browser, and buttons on this page don't work.

I heard that old version of Java Machine can cause this problem, so I have updated it to the last one. Also I've tried to open this "wizard-page" in different browsers (like Opera or Google Chrome) - the same result. And if I try to open it in Internet Explorer, it asks me again: "Open or Save"... :-/

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

The wizard is based on a webbrowser control, which is subject to IE's security settings. Try reset your IE options.